# Cursor not blinking in templated TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have the following TextBox in one of my views:

```
<TextBox Name="SearchTerm" Style="{StaticResource SearchTermTextBoxStyle}"
         Text="{Binding TemplatesViewModel.SearchTerm, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         attachedProperties:Watermark.Watermark="Some watermark text"
         KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="5" />
```

Which has, as you can see, the following style applied:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchTermTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding (attachedProperties:Watermark.Watermark), Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" x:Name="DefaultTextPrompt"
                           Foreground="#888888" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Hidden"
                           Margin="5,-1,0,0" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="DefaultTextPrompt" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that when I obtain a focus on the SearchTerm TextBox, the cursor will not appear at all. First that came to my mind was simple conclusion: probably I get logical focus only, not keyboard focus. But that is not true. I can freely type in some text into that TextBox and I am still not getting cursor. When I am entering this TextBox using left mouse button, cursor appears and is blinking as expected.
What is wrong with my TextBox then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on the `TextBox` control that you put inside the `TextBox`'s `ControlTemplate`. I suppose when you focus on the (parent) `TextBox`, it does not focus on the `ControlTemplate`'s `TextBox`.

When you use left click, it just goes directly to the `ControlTemplate`'s `TextBox`, so you have blinking cursor.

If you notice in the original (default) `TextBox`'s `ControlTemplate`, it uses `ScrollViewer` to host the content, so I would recommend you to change

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

to

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
```

This will automagically show the `Text` from the `TemplatedParent`. And also let you focus on the (parent) `TextBox`.